# Find components binded to store in ExtJS 5.1.x

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a *gridpanel* and a binded *store*, all configured with objects. *Store* has "*load*" event.

Is there anyway to get components (in that case *gridpanel* "fooo") inside "*load*" event that are connected to the *store*?

```
Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    viewModel: new Ext.app.ViewModel({
        name: "globalVM",
        stores: {
            fooo: {
                autoLoad: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: "ajax",
                    url: "/data.json",
                    reader: {
                        type: "json",
                        rootProperty: "results"
                    }
                },
                listeners: {
                    scope: this,
                    load: function(ejStore, records, successful, eOpts)
                    {
                        var grid;                       
                        // obtain connected gridpanel "fooo" component???
                        grid.getView();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }),
    items:[{
            xtype: "gridpanel",
            columns: [{
                        dataIndex: "title",
                        text: "Title"
                    }],
            name: "fooo",
            bind : {
                store: "{fooo}"
            }
    }]
});
```

Comment: The only way I can think of is use the query method on the Main view, get all its descendants and check which component has a store "fooo"

Comment: Maybe you shood look to the dynamically grid/store creation, using `initComponent` method